# How to combine the items of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = [1,2,3]
```

what I want is `["a1", "b2","c3"]`

It looks like I can't use append(), extend() or insert() to archive it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). SO is not a coding service, it is a community of enthusiasts who help each other with specific problems. Please write some code and if it doesn't work, post the code along with your input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you want:

```
list3 = list(a + str(b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assume size of both lists are the same, the straightforward way is to iterate over both lists together using an index.

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = [1,2,3]

list3 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3.append("{}{}".format(list1[i], list2[i]))
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```